# windows 10 system tray icons appear out of place

Tags: windows-10, taskbar

I have this problem where my system tray icons appear out of place. I have tried updating the display driver but with no luck. Does anybody know what might be causing this issue?

Here a screen shot of the task bar:

[image]

Comment: make a rightclick on taskbar bar und uncheck "lock taskbar", look if you can now re-arrange them correctly